# Print pdf from url java

Tags: java, pdf, printing

I have to print a pdf from a URL. I had read a lot of websites but, I have not found a solution. I´m using JAVA 7 for my project. Could somebody help me with this problem? (example, website, manual, code)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a servlet - HTTP listener - that's listening for HTTP GET/POST requests to that URL.

The servlet will need to generate the PDF and write the bytes to the output stream.

You have at least two choices for generating the PDF: XSL-FO, which is a good choice if the data is XML, or iText, a Java library that creates a PDF in code.

If the file already exists on the file system you just need to read the bytes and stream them to the output stream.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but i do not understand. I recibed my pdf (for example this: "http://vrstc.org/waterpolo/rules.pdf") in a variable of Json, and If I want print this pdf, I need pass to bytes this pdf?

Comment: If that's the URL that you were sent in JSON - where do you get the PDF contents?  The user shouldn't be passing bytes here.  It's a GET request - they want you to send back the document they've requested.  You either have it, create it, or tell them it's not available.

Comment: Then you can not print a document that is in an FTP or in my computer?

Comment: I want to receive the URL of the PDF by Json variable, and then tell the printer to print the document. This is possible? Thank you for yours answers!

Comment: Wherever that PDF is, the server that accepts the request will have to get it, read the bytes, and stream them down to the caller.  It's possible, but not if you fail to understand this response.

Comment: Is it possible to read the document in the URL as bytes through JAVA. The file is already available in the URL and can be reached from outside.

Comment: Of course it is - java.io.InputStream and java.io.OutputStream do it.